# High performance wrapper for Scala-to-Java collections conversion

Tags: java, scala, performance

Say I have a Java class with some business logic:

```java
package examples;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Inner {
    public void consume(Map<Integer, List<Double>> map) {
        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println("Key: " + k);
            v.forEach(i -> System.out.println("  item: " + i));
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a *high performance, as native as possible* Scala wrapper(because this wrapper may be called in high frequency), so:

### The First Attempt

```scala
package examples

class Wrapper(val asJava: Inner) extends AnyVal {
  implicit def consume(map: Map[Int, List[Double]]): Unit = asJava.consume(map)
}
```

But got errors:

```
[error]  found   : Map[Int,List[Double]]               (in scala.collection.immutable)
[error]  required: Map[Integer,java.util.List[Double]] (in java.util)
[error]   implicit def consume(map: Map[Int, List[Double]]): Unit = asJava.consume(map)
[error]                                                                            ^
[error] one error found
```

### The Second Attempt

```scala
package examples

import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

class Wrapper(val asJava: Inner) extends AnyVal {
  implicit def consume(map: Map[Int, List[Double]]): Unit = asJava.consume(map.asJava)
}
```

Still got errors:

```
[error]  found   : java.util.Map[Int,List[scala.Double]]
[error]  required: java.util.Map[Integer,java.util.List[java.lang.Double]]
[error]   implicit def consume(map: Map[Int, List[Double]]): Unit = asJava.consume(map.asJava)
[error]                                                                                ^
[error] one error found
```

**And I am afraid that `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` may allocate extra memory and waste a lot of time**

### Questions

1. Can I use `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` in high performance scenario?
2. In Kotlin, all of the primitive types and most of collections can be converted to / from their Java alternative **with almost no performance lose**, so I wonder how to achieve the goal in Scala?

Comment: Discussion in progress [here](https://gitter.im/scala/scala?at=5e25d8f60a1cf5414490b5d0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**: I've expanded on the answer to provide more detail and explanation.

Use `Integer` instead of `Int`, and `java.lang.Double` instead of `scala.Double` (which is what `Double` is interpreted to be in *Scala*) in your *Scala* definitions.

The problem is that *Java* does not allow the use of primitives in collections, which is why it uses `Integer` instead of `int` as the type, and `Double` instead of `double`. In *Scala*, the treatment of `Int`, `Double`, etc. is more complex. It will treat them as primitives (i.e., like *Java*'s `int`, `double`, etc.) in most cases, but it will box (and unbox) them when used with collections.

However, when inter-operating with *Java*, it's necessary to be more explicit. *Scala* will implicitly convert `Integer` instances to `Int` instances—and *vice versa*—when necessary, but it cannot implicitly convert collections of boxed primitives.

You can use the *Java* collections in *Scala* just fine, with zero overhead; you don't need to convert them to *Scala* equivalents at all. However, you will obviously need to perform conversions if you pass them to code that expects *Scala*'s equivalent collections, or if you want to use *Scala* collections with your legacy *Java* code. (In case it's not clear, a `java.util.Map` is not the same as a `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, nor is a `java.util.List` the same as a `scala.collection.immutable.List`. The *Scala* collections are immutable and designed for efficient use using a *functional programming* paradigm.)

If you're concerned about performance, you should use a micro-benchmarking toolkit, such as *[ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/)*, which will allow you to measure, precisely, comparisons of using the *Java* collections natively versus converting to/from *Scala* collections.

**UPDATE 2**:

I've re-written your first attempt, using *Java*'s collections. To avoid confusion with *Scala* types, I've renamed the clashing *Java* types by prefixing them with `J`:

```scala
package examples

import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}
import java.util.{List => JList, Map => JMap}
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Wrapper(val asJava: Inner) {
  implicit def consume(map: JMap[Integer, JList[JDouble]]): Unit = {
    asJava.consume(map)
  }
}
```

This uses the Java `Map` and `List` collections, as well as the boxed primitives. It compiles, but it buys you absolutely nothing (the signature of `Wrapper.consume` is exactly the same as `Inner.consume`). However, it does illustrate how to use the *Java* collections *in situ* in *Scala*.

If you want to use *Scala* collections, and convert to the *Java* equivalents, which I think is the intention of your second attempt, then that would look like this:

```scala
package examples

import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Wrapper(val asJava: Inner) {
  implicit def consume(map: Map[Int, List[Double]]): Unit = {
    val jmap = map.asInstanceOf[Map[Integer, List[JDouble]]]
    asJava.consume(jmap.map(p => p._1 -> p._2.asJava).asJava)
  }
}
```

In this case, we first have to cast the collection to use the boxed types (the definitions are equivalent under the hood), which has no overhead as such.

Then we have to convert the *Scala* data structures to the equivalent *Java* data structures. There's clearly an overhead in doing this, if only to wrap the *Scala* data structures in a *Java* interface.

**UPDATE 3**

I should also point out that making the `Wrapper.consume` method `implicit` is an odd choice. I think you maybe intended to make the class `implicit`, so that (in the second attempt) you can implicitly consume *Scala* data structures with an `Inner` instance. (In effect, `Inner` gets decorated by the functions provided in `Wrapper`.) `Inner` instances will be implicitly converted to `Wrapper` instances, with no overhead (this will not even create an instance of `Wrapper` in most cases, because of the `extending AnyVal` clause):

```scala
import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import scala.language.implicitConversions

package object examples {
  implicit class Wrapper(val asJava: Inner) extends AnyVal {
    def consume(map: Map[Int, List[Double]]): Unit = {
      val jmap = map.asInstanceOf[Map[Integer, List[JDouble]]]
      asJava.consume(jmap.map(p => p._1 -> p._2.asJava).asJava)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `Wrapper` now needs to be defined inside a `package object`. (This is because implicit classes can only be defined within an `object` of some kind, which must be brought into scope, and a `package object` is generally the most convenient way to achieve this.)

Answer (score 1):

`asJava`/`asScala` create simple wrappers. They allocate a single extra object and most methods will just delegate to the underlying collection. But the thing is, Java's collection classes are already very far from optimal for primitives; instead there are quite a few primitive collection libraries around. [This 2015 article](http://java-performance.info/hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove-january-2015/) lists FastUtil, Goldman Sachs, HPPC, Koloboke, Trove. There are also [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) and probably more I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jmh benchmark indicating `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` have negligible cost

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So59827649 {
  def consumeScala(inner: Inner, map: Map[Int, List[Double]]): Unit = {
    val jmap = map.asInstanceOf[Map[Integer, List[java.lang.Double]]];
    inner.consume(jmap.map(p => p._1 -> p._2.asJava).asJava)
  }

  def consumeJava(inner: Inner, map: java.util.Map[Integer, java.util.List[java.lang.Double]]): Unit = {
    inner.consume(map)
  }

  val inner = new Inner
  val size = 1000
  val scalaMap = (1 to size).map(i => i ->  List.fill(size)(math.random)).toMap
  val javaMap = (1 to size).map(i => int2Integer(i) -> List.fill(size)(double2Double(math.random)).asJava).toMap.asJava

  @Benchmark def _consumeScala(): Unit = consumeScala(inner, scalaMap)
  @Benchmark def _consumeJava(): Unit = consumeJava(inner, javaMap)
}
```

and

```
public class Inner {
    public void consume(java.util.Map<Integer, java.util.List<Double>> map) {
        map.forEach((k, v) -> v.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum());
    }
}
```

where `sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 5 -f 2 -t 1 bench.So59827649"` gives

```
[info] Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
[info] So59827649._consumeJava   thrpt   20  97.963 ± 0.980  ops/s
[info] So59827649._consumeScala  thrpt   20  96.350 ± 2.326  ops/s
```